# Get Path to folder on phone connected to windows computer

Tags: java, android, windows, file, directory

Does Java have access to an android phones files system connected to a windows computer via USB?  It does not show up in the JFileChooser and is not lists as a root in File.listroots();  Is there anyway to access the file system?  (I am not opposed to using JNI)

Comment: What do you mean with Java? The Java IDE on a Linux computer somewhere on the internet? Or where?

Comment: Running a Java application on a Windows Computer that has a phone connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Android phones communicate with a Windows PC using the MTP protocol.

So you should use that.